# How to collect values (data) of dynamically added rows (HTML table) ? Using php & XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, xampp

I created a simple form with a dynamic table. This table rows increment by the user input values, so I need to increment the combo box or the select (option) every time a new row created, so it should be like default combo box values. Note: this select or combo box is part of the column attributes, remember the rows increment, but without the column.

2nd Question:

I want to collect this table columns data or values whatever its rows number is, and store it to XAMPP database using php. I know how to collect data from a single form, but I don't know how to collect data from dynamic form.

Here is the code:

```
function AddRows()
{
var tableelement = document.getElementById("mytable")
var rows = document.getElementById("noofrows").value;
var tablerowcount = tableelement.rows.length;
var currowcount = tablerowcount;


for(i = 1; i < rows; i++) {

var row = tableelement.insertRow(currowcount);
var cellid = row.insertCell(0);
cellid.innerHTML = "<b>" + currowcount +"</b>";
var cellid2 = row.insertCell(1);


cellid2.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" + currowcount +"_name' /> ";
var cellid3 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid3.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" + currowcount +"_name' /> ";
var cellid4 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid4.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" + currowcount +"_name' /> ";
var cellid5 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid5.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" +currowcount +"_name' /> ";
var cellid6 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid6.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" +currowcount+"_name' /> ";


var currowcountcurrowcount = currowcount++;


}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insert.php>

Carton Number :<input type="text" name="cn"> <br>
Business Unit :<input type="text" name="bu"> <br>
No of Files  :<input type="noofrows" id="noofrows"  value="1" name="nof" />

<input name="add" id="add" type="button" value="Add" onClick="AddRows()"/>


<table name="mytable" id="mytable" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <b>SN</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>From</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>To</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>Range</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>Document Category</b>
        </td>
        <td>
          <b>Document Type</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <b>1</b>
    </td>
    <td>
       <input value="" id='1_name' >
    </b>
</td>
<td>
       <input value="" id='1_name'/>
    </b>
</td>
<td>
   <input value="" id='1_name' />
 </b>
    </td>

  <td>
  <Select id='select' />
    <option name="option" value="finance">Finance Documents</option>
    <option name="option" value="hr">HR Documents</option>
    <option name="option" value="test">test</option
    </Select>
  </b>
    </td>
    <td>

    <Select id='select' />
       <option name="option" value="CP">Cash movement</option>
       <option name="option" value="PV">Payment Voucher</option>
       <option name="option" value="RV">RV</option
    </Select>
    </b>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
```

Comment: Just a comment on your HTML: `id` attributes shall be unique. You've got two `select` elements with "select" as `id`

Comment: it's not the final code i'am just declaring my idea :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function AddRows()
{
var tableelement = document.getElementById("mytable")
var rows = document.getElementById("noofrows").value;
var tablerowcount = tableelement.rows.length;
var currowcount = tablerowcount;


for(i = 1; i < rows; i++) {

var row = tableelement.insertRow(currowcount);
var cellid = row.insertCell(0);
cellid.innerHTML = "<b>" + currowcount +"</b>";
var cellid2 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid2.innerHTML = "<Select id='select' /><option name='option' value='CP'>Cash movement</option><option name='option' value='PV'>Payment Voucher</option>   <option name='option' value='RV'>RV</option></Select> ";
var cellid3 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid3.innerHTML = "<Select id='select' /><option name='option' value='finance'>Finance Documents</option><option name='option' value='hr'>HR Documents</option><option name='option' value='test'>test</option</Select> ";
var cellid4 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid4.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" + currowcount +"_name' /> ";
var cellid5 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid5.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" +currowcount +"_name' /> ";
var cellid6 = row.insertCell(1);
cellid6.innerHTML = "<input value='' id='" +currowcount+"_name' /> ";


var currowcountcurrowcount = currowcount++;


}
}
</script>
```

change in your function to get the selection for every row
and to save data first you change the all  inputs and selections id as  array variable
ex id='1_name_Range[]'for range.  also change in the function
renaming code for save you know well as you say.used the array variable to save in database